# Does Microsoft have a non-hack method for turning off the 'X' to disconnect terminal RDP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-terminal-services

Hoping this goes here...

We have issues when users disconnect from terminal services instead of logging off. Does Microsoft have a non-hack method for disabling the Close caption on the taskbar as well as disabling the 'X' in the control options?

Our clients run on Windows 7 and Windows XP. No matter how many times you tell them not to use the 'X' to disconnect, they do it anyway - and, of course, causes issues when they try to log in again before the terminal server has a chance to clean up any dangling disconnects.

Comment: What happens when your clients actually do disconnect, i.e., their network plug gets tripped over, there's a power outage, their computer crashes, etc.?

Comment: @Kev: of course, there are those occurrences where the user calls us and we reset the connection. It seems as though (and I wouldn't know because I don't work on that end of things) you can't set a timeout on idle connection to clean up truly disconnected sessions without affecting the sessions that are still connected yet idle. We want users to remain connected even if idle, yet clean up the connections that get disconnected. Make sense?

Comment: Of course, it doesn't really make sense that MS wouldn't have a setting for the .RDP config file that would simply remove the buttons.

Comment: Ah, I see.  And that would be relatively infrequent since they're all local/controlled.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right solution is probably to log out idle sessions (see Group Policy) after some timeout period rather than trying to influence client-side behavior. There's a ton of RDP clients out there, and they don't all run on Windows.

Comment: Our clients are limited to Windows and the standard mstsc.exe that MS distributes. I know the proper solution, but getting the left hand to acquiesce to the right hand's request is easier said than done in this case. If there is a non-hack method for disabling the Close button and 'X', it would actually be easier to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a GPO setting to automatically logoff "disconnected" sessions after a period of time, that way people can leave their sessions idle but still connected without the fear of being disconnected, and people just closing their RDP client will be correctly disconnected.

Comment: I'll pass this suggestion along to see if it can get implemented (and if it indeed will do what we want).